# CakePHP $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl()); Duplicates BaseURL in Redirect

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-routing

In CakePHP v2.3.8, after a user logs in, I want to send them to the page they were trying to access. CakePHP is running out of a subdirectory (baseurl in the example below):

`$this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());` sends me to:

```
http://example.com/baseurl/baseurl/controller/action
```

It should send me to:

```
http://example.com/baseurl/controller/action
```

Is anyone else getting a duplicated base url in their redirects? Does anybody know how to fix it? *This is my first time using CakePHP, so please let me know if I'm not asking the right question or providing the needed information.* Thanks!

Note: I see a similar addressed as [a bug in RC version 2.4](https://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/projects/42648/tickets/3938-this-redirectthis-auth-redirecturl-broken). However, I'm running v2.3.8, so I don't think this is the exact issue. The fix in [this commit](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/commit/a70e004cda6dd4f87d16d2bba21c48d63127eacf) looks identical to my code in v2.3.8.

Comment: We’re going to need to see some code before we could even *begin* to guess what’s going on.

Comment: Apparently this issue is the same/similar as a documented bug in an RC version: https://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/projects/42648/tickets/3938-this-redirectthis-auth-redirecturl-broken

Comment: "is anyone else having this issue?" is not a question appropriate for Stack overflow

Comment: @AD7six Unfortunately, the documented bug is in an RC version that I'm not running (2.4). I'm running the sable version of 2.3.8.

Comment: which means it's not the problem (in which case there's no relevant information at all) or it is a problem but isn't thought to apply before 2.4 - either way - you should edit the question with **more information**. You've just edited the question and still don't mention you're installed in a subdirectory.

Comment: @MartinBean I would be happy to provide code, however I don't know what code you would want to see... Do you want to see the controller code? Do you want to see the config files?

Comment: Similar issue in cakephp v2.6 but I resolved it.
Seem my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26363825/cakephp-bad-auth-redirection/27813239#27813239

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with line 680 of lib/Cake/Controller/Component/AuthComponent.php

```
return Router::url($redir);
```

Changing it to the following (which was an update in 2.3.9) fixes it:

```
return Router::url($redir + array('base' => false));
```

As does changing it to this (which is an update in 2.4):

```
return Router::normalize($redir, false);
```

See commit message here:
https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/commit/8133f72

Obviously editing the CakePHP core files isn't a good idea, so I upgraded to 2.3.9 to fix the issue.